# removing the last punctuation character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, text, punctuation

i know this question is susceptible to be marked as a duplicate, but after searching in the website i didn't find anything that matches what i really want to do.

I have a string like this :

```
string = "hey, that's you(this is a test)!"
```

i'm working on a function that removes only the last punctuation mark in any string, not punctuation embedded on a word, nor the leading punctuation signs,this function should also store the word frequencies in a dictionary.

This my code so far:

```
def word_counts(string):
    s = string.lower().split()
    dic = {}

    for key in string:
        key = "".join([l for l in key if l.isalpha()])

        if key in dic :
            dic[key] += 1

        else:
            dic[key] = 1


    return dic
```

my code is yelling the following results:

```
{'a': 1, 'hey': 1, 'is': 1, 'test': 1, 'thats': 1, 'youthis': 1}
```

but what i need is:

```
{'a': 1, 'hey': 1, 'is': 1, 'test)': 1, 'that's': 1, 'you': 1, (this': 1}
```

Note that in the word `'test)'` the exclamation sign is removed but the parenthesis needs to stay. Any clues about how to do this??

Thank you all in advance

EDIT:

the comma after "hey" should leave. I should only remove one punctuation sign at a time, so if i find 2 at the end of a word, only one is to be removed.

Comment: Why is the right parenthesis after 'test' kept but not the comma after 'hey'? Is it because the comma is last in a "word" but the parenthesis is not? How should an apostrophe at the end of a word be treated (such as "Parents' Day" or "Jesus' love")?

Comment: sorry, i wrote my desired result manually, i'll edit and fix. Technically for what you are asking me, those apostrophes are embedded between 2 words, so they should stay. they should be treated like the `"that's"` word

Comment: Why is you(this not a single word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about checking for any possible punctuation mark
and returning a stripped string when found one?

```
import string

def strip_last_punctuation(s):
    if s and s[-1] in string.punctuation:
        return s[:-1]
    else:
        return s

test_str = "hey, that's you(this is a test)!"
print(strip_last_punctuation(test_str))
```

EDIT: Removed unnecessary `for` loop.

Comment: The last character check could be done without a loop: `if s[-1] in string.punctuation: ...`

Comment: @taras thanks a lot buddy, that was exactly what i needed. upvoted answer and marked as correct!! i have learnt something new today thanks to you!!

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers seem to be good, anyway I'll suggest to consider a regex approach.
Just check, for each word, wether is present a punctuation character and if yes remove it.

Here an example:

```
import re

t = 'test.'
punctuations = '[!,\.:;"\']'
m = re.search( punctuations, t )
t.replace( m.group(0), '')
#out: 'test'
```